# I want to implement instance normalization

Tags: ios, deep-learning, gpu, metal, compute-shader

I am writing a metal cnn code.
Metal provides MPSCNNLocalContrastNormalization,
Since the concept of Instance Normalization is slightly different, I intend to implement it as a Kernel Function.

However, the problem is that the mean and variance for each R, G, B should be obtained when feature is R, G, B in texture received from input in kernel function.
I want to get some hints on how to implement this.

[image]

```
kernel void instance_normalization_2darray(texture2d_array<float, access::sample> src [[ texture(0) ]],
                                        texture2d_array<float, access::write> dst [[ texture(1) ]],
                                        uint3 tid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {

}


    kernel void calculate_avgA(texture2d_array<float, access::read> texture_in [[texture(0)]],
                          texture2d_array<float, access::write> texture_out [[texture(1)]],
                          uint3 tid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    int width = texture_in.get_width();
    int height = texture_in.get_height();
    int depth = texture_in.get_array_size();
    float4 outColor;


    uint3 kernelIndex(0,0,0);
    uint3 textureIndex(0,0,0);

    for(int k = 0; k < depth; k++) {
        outColor = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        for (int i=0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j < height; j++)
            {
                kernelIndex = uint3(i, j, k);
                textureIndex = uint3(tid.x + i, tid.y + j, tid.z + k);
                float4 color = texture_in.read(textureIndex.xy, textureIndex.z).rgba;
                outColor += color;
            }
        }
        outColor = outColor / (width * height);
        texture_out.write(float4(outColor.rgba), tid.xy, textureIndex.z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mr.Bista
I had the same problem for this, apple didn't provide some function for this with fast speed.
And I just use MPSCNNPoolingAverage for caculate mean before kernels.
Maybe it is a temporary method for it.
And other algorithm is not better than this ,such as reduction sum algorithm after my test with codes.
So I will continue to track better implementation for this.

Comment: Wow! Good Idea..!!
After I average with mpscnnpoolingaverage, can you give me some hints on how to get the variance ..?

Comment: After mpscnnpoolingaverage , you can get a mpstemporaryimage with nchannelx1x1 (1x1 pixle). And then you can use a kernel to calculate sub and power of sub image from original image, and do pooling average again, you will get variance.

Comment: And I will give another algorithm with reduction sum refer to INVIDA optimisation algorithm in my MetalImage project in Github.(https://github.com/erickingxu/MetalImage.git)

Comment: Thank you. !! I implemented it based on the hint you gave me, but the speed is slow when my texture is 160 x 92 x 128 (width, height, depth).
Is there a way to improve this?
Sample code is attached to the text.

Comment: It would be great if you can provide your code sample for the full instance normalisation, cause I am struggeling with the variance! Thanks!